# Error when trying to use OP_CHECKSEQUENCEVERIFY from bip112 on testnet

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-core

When I try to spend an utxo sent to a pay to script hash, with the script `5 OP_CHECKSEQUENCEVERIFY OP_DROP OP_PUBKEY OP_CHECKSIG` I get the following error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$ bitcoin-cli --rpcuser=bitcoinrpcuser --rpcpassword=bitcoinrpcpass --rpcport=18332 sendrawtransaction 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
error code: -26
error message:
64: non-mandatory-script-verify-flag (NOPx reserved for soft-fork upgrades)

$ bitcoin-cli --rpcuser=bitcoinrpcuser --rpcpassword=bitcoinrpcpass --rpcport=18332 decoderawtransaction 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
{
  "txid": "c927276d8ac392b88225ae25d596b8e3f658195232200a1fe83788497bc46c66",
  "size": 574,
  "version": 2,
  "locktime": 0,
  "vin": [
    {
      "txid": "ea3652430512b13b5269dcee67bb3d3cb21460b7b2e51c6d846607ace6990653",
      "vout": 0,
      "scriptSig": {
        "asm": "3045022100d48af25c0e1816dd0007bdb0907ae2c4cf96602fb41a089a975eba017f9295af022000af5806f68ac0ba6ac2ada355e8f6050ccfb4d7020ff7d22788be10a07d51a9[ALL] 55b27521027690887ac2455b6b19c5f4268a8a9c09228351368b9a7643ad791282c3148759ac",
        "hex": "483045022100d48af25c0e1816dd0007bdb0907ae2c4cf96602fb41a089a975eba017f9295af022000af5806f68ac0ba6ac2ada355e8f6050ccfb4d7020ff7d22788be10a07d51a9012655b27521027690887ac2455b6b19c5f4268a8a9c09228351368b9a7643ad791282c3148759ac"
      },
      "sequence": 5
    }, 
    {
      "txid": "ffa745b9259fcfdda916f755e68d4480a564887ae460d586a7b46db9d48c4a00",
      "vout": 0,
      "scriptSig": {
        "asm": "30450221009914d50bfcc49b1f539824c04f8bc22520906dd24be8cbf5d3c9eafd78e8b1400220305d70a8888e1b8f7bbbaef0e1b3d8d1b9509561f4fff53b194315989122ffb1[ALL] 55b27521027690887ac2455b6b19c5f4268a8a9c09228351368b9a7643ad791282c3148759ac",
        "hex": "4830450221009914d50bfcc49b1f539824c04f8bc22520906dd24be8cbf5d3c9eafd78e8b1400220305d70a8888e1b8f7bbbaef0e1b3d8d1b9509561f4fff53b194315989122ffb1012655b27521027690887ac2455b6b19c5f4268a8a9c09228351368b9a7643ad791282c3148759ac"
      },
      "sequence": 5
    }, 
    {
      "txid": "4d47bd2d69fb8f5090ce7f3514903b60c75b2908bff980ce77a39583bd1e9207",
      "vout": 0,
      "scriptSig": {
        "asm": "30450221008fab401cba85dcc1aac10d9949ca066e8c2cd86ca153a1e0059d839372bf8f12022066c97d30d95286185497d2f9622642ef7d9e511e8c4f2686c9d12504273ac80d[ALL] 55b27521027690887ac2455b6b19c5f4268a8a9c09228351368b9a7643ad791282c3148759ac",
        "hex": "4830450221008fab401cba85dcc1aac10d9949ca066e8c2cd86ca153a1e0059d839372bf8f12022066c97d30d95286185497d2f9622642ef7d9e511e8c4f2686c9d12504273ac80d012655b27521027690887ac2455b6b19c5f4268a8a9c09228351368b9a7643ad791282c3148759ac"
      },
      "sequence": 5
    }
  ],
  "vout": [
    {
      "value": 0.00005430,
      "n": 0,
      "scriptPubKey": {
        "asm": "OP_DUP OP_HASH160 0d98bebd47d04361d889e11a977a9ab61665d591 OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG",
        "hex": "76a9140d98bebd47d04361d889e11a977a9ab61665d59188ac",
        "reqSigs": 1,
        "type": "pubkeyhash",
        "addresses": [
          "mgkr4TjXCGMJSpcoQGi6wDkr72NTtkuMDs"
        ]
      }
    }, 
    {
      "value": 0.00000000,
      "n": 1,
      "scriptPubKey": {
        "asm": "OP_RETURN 0131b3774cfeb0198684fce15e0fdf7709e830c9387a1ac6e99b6647",
        "hex": "6a1c0131b3774cfeb0198684fce15e0fdf7709e830c9387a1ac6e99b6647",
        "type": "nulldata"
      }
    }, 
    {
      "value": 0.00095430,
      "n": 2,
      "scriptPubKey": {
        "asm": "OP_HASH160 9c202ce4f6cafc3420271e79be29911288c51326 OP_EQUAL",
        "hex": "a9149c202ce4f6cafc3420271e79be29911288c5132687",
        "reqSigs": 1,
        "type": "scripthash",
        "addresses": [
          "2N7UjwnxwetBQB8pEaufas4bhS6wh4JjBoy"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Edit:

When I replace the OP_CHECKSEQUENCEVERIFY with a OP_NOP I can spend it just fine.

As demonstrated by the p2sh address [2N6PWjG9eFjuKcxHf8pvQdHityorvyAerFT](https://test-insight.bitpay.com/address/2N6PWjG9eFjuKcxHf8pvQdHityorvyAerFT) for the script `1 OP_NOP OP_DROP OP_PUBKEY OP_CHECKSIG`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not running version 0.12.1 of bitcoind, as I mistakenly didn't overwrite the binary when upgrading.

Now that I have upgraded it has been accepted into the mempool and I expect it to be included in a block as soon as upgraded miner includes it.

Answer (score 0):

What are you setting the input's nSequence value to?

Comment: 5 as can be seen in the decoded raw transaction above, however I think I may just have used an outdated bitcoind by mistake. Currently recompiling to verify.